# g_hash_table and OpenMp

Tags: c++, c, openmp, glib

Are `g_hash_table_lookup` and `g_hash_table_insert` thread-safe? Can I use code like this:

```
dict = g_hash_table_new();
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    compute_A();
    find_hash_of_A();
    void *value = g_hash_table_lookup(dict, key);
    struct MyStruct *obj;
    if (!value) {
        obj = (struct MyStruct *)value;
    } else {
        compute_obj
        g_hash_table_insert(dict, key, obj);
    }
    do_something_with_obj
}
```

with `#pragma omp parallel for`, or I need to use some other OpenMP pragmas?
At times I got an error in that loop. One thread version works fine.

Comment: You should surround all calls to `g_hash_table_*` from inside the parallel region with `#pragma omp critical { ... }` (the curly braces go on the next line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  From the [Threads section of the GLib Reference Manual](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Threads.html):

> GLib itself is internally completely thread-safe (all global data is automatically locked), but individual data structure instances are not automatically locked for performance reasons. For example, you must coordinate accesses to the same [GHashTable](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html#GHashTable) from multiple threads. The two notable exceptions from this rule are [GMainLoop](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#GMainLoop) and [GAsyncQueue](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Asynchronous-Queues.html#GAsyncQueue), which are thread-safe and need no further application-level locking to be accessed from multiple threads. Most refcounting functions such as [`g_object_ref()`](http://developer.gnome.org/gobject/unstable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#g-object-ref) are also thread-safe.

Comment: _For example, you must coordinate accesses to the same GHashTable from multiple threads._ Doesn't this mean that I have to use pragmas to work with GHashTable?

Comment: The original question was "Are g_hash_table_lookup and g_hash_table_insert thread-safe?", and the answer is "No."  If you can use OpenMP pragmas to restrict access to a single thread then that would be an option.  You could also use something like GMutex.